# Ethereum: how can you find out if there are any hidden slippage fees on buying/selling token?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Either in Web3 or Sol.
Before trading tokens I am trying to determine what the exact amount will be which I will receive given slippage, and also to understand how many tokens I would receive if I was to then trade back immidiately after. I am trying to know roughly what the token price would need to increase to to recover any fees from buying and selling.
Some tokens I have seen take slippage fee for burns, liquidity, auto distribution etc. Also, when using Metamask, if I don't set slippage high enough Metamask will error before the tx is sent so no GWEI is spent. How can I acheive something similar where I can determine how much slippage is needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a tough question to answer , that solely falls down to the fact that its hard to automatically get the fees for a certain token.
Manually however , I imagine with your expertise in coding you can read that easily through the contract.

However I have two plausible solutions here.

1. some contracts have their read fees as a public function
   meaning you can acquire how much they take for fees via a function call
   as you may suspect however this presents a lot of problems most notably not every contract has these , and also the read function's name to get fees inflicted changes from contract to another
2. Recommended way but also hard: you can technically take the contract's address and its ABI and deploy it on a local testing blockchain like ganache and initiate a a swap to that contract (You would also need to fork uniswap on your local blockchain) and from there you can calculate how many tokens you lost as a roundtrip all automatically
   for example if you simulated a buy of 500 tokens and you came out with 400 tokens then the buy tax is 20%.
   you can do the same thing for the sell and find out that tax on sells.
   I understand this is a complicated and hard way to find out fees on tokens but this is the only 100% guaranteed way of doing it.

a third solution but not so automatic , is to manually put in the fees for that contract after reading the smart contract yourself